# Ionic remote images not loading

Tags: android, image, ionic-framework

I was today installing ionic framework and running a newly created app. The commands I was running were the following:

```
ionic start myApp tabs
ionic platform add android
ionic run android
```

I've seen that the example app contains already some content. The weird thing is that the images contained in the example don't seem able to load when running on a device. They instead load perfectly running `ionic serve`.

The only thing I've noticed is that the images are not local to the app but are remote eg. `https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/491274378181488640/Tti0fFVJ.jpeg`.

Changing device the app seems to be working. Only difference between the devices is the android version (4.3 does not work and 4.4 seems to be working fine).

Any suggestion to make remote images load everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try adding crosswalk to your project (http://blog.ionic.io/2015/01/12/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic/). For me it solved lots of bugs ocurring on different android versions.

Hope it helps

Comment: It is what I've done at the end. It was just weird that the default WebView was not able to handle this.